# Does occupational / workplace psychology have a name for local managers using the "Barnum Effect"

Tags: management, team, teamwork, psychology

The Barnum effect is when astrologers, tarot readers etc statements about your personality or your future that you think is specific to you but in fact are very general and apply to almost anyone just by nature of being a human. They only work because we readily take them on board. You might think you wouldn't get hood winked but its an accusation levelled at many of personality tests that are carried out "as a bit of fun" in many workplaces.

But I have seen a more general case where local managers with no technical background make make similiar statements. They aren't talking about people's personalities or their future but about the team's structure and collective actions. They don't refer to the specifics of our technical team but make platitudes that could apply to any workplace. Think "better communication", "become self organising".

Does workplace / occupational psychology have a name for this more general phenomenon?

Comment: Are you saying that managers shouldn't encourage teams to communicate better or self organise, because those are meaningless terms?

Comment: The fact that something is a platitude doesn't make it incorrect, or mean that it can't be something to focus on and improve. ***EVERYONE*** can improve communication, and should continuously be trying to do so, and it doesn't hurt to remind people that this is, in fact, something that management expects from them. If you don't think it applies to you in particular, feel free to ignore it -- at your own risk if you're misjudging. Personally, it sounds like you aren't listening for intent and are nitpicking language, which strikes me as something you could focus on to improve communication.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it reads as a rant rather than a question.

Comment: I don't know about other industries, but engineers call this bulshido

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about what I think you are talking about - then terms like 'Buzzword Bingo' and 'Corporate Speak' and the eponymous 'BS' come to mind.

To make sure you are talking about what I think you mean:

A Manager comes in and says 'We need to really look at disruptive technologies, so we can pivot our ecosystem and remain agile - whilst leveraging our existing tech stack'

What does that even mean? 9 times out of ten, it's just a bunch of fancy sounding words that all the cool kids are using and makes the manager sound knowledgable and on the cutting edge.

Comment: "Add the newest shiny framework that caught my eye but is going to be outdated/replaced next week"?